# Evaluating Gaussian Mixture model using a score metric?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, gaussian, data-fitting, mixture-model

I have 1D data (on column data). I used Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM) as a density estimation, using this implementation in Python: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html. By relying on AIC/BIC criteron i was able to determine number of components. After i fit the GMM, i plotted kernel density estimation of original observation + that of sampled data drawn from GMM. the plot of original and sampled desnities are quiet similar( that is good). But, i would like some metrics to report how good is the fitted model.

```
g = GaussianMixture(n_components = 35)

data= df['x'].values.reshape(-1,1) # data taken from data frame (10,000 data pints)
clf= g.fit(data)# fit model

samples= clf.sample(10000)[0] # generate sample data points (same # as original data points)
```

I found score in the implementation, but not sure how to implememnt. Am i doing it wrong? or is there any better way to show how accuracy is the fitted model, apart from histogram or kernel densities plots?.

```
print(clf.score(data))
print(clf.score(samples))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `normalized_mutual_info_score`, `adjusted_rand_score` or `silhouette` score to evaluate your clusters. All of these metrics are implemented under `sklearn.metrics` section.

**EDIT**: You can check this [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering-performance-evaluation) for more detail explanations.

In a summary:

- **Adjusted Rand Index**: measures the similarity of the two assignments.
- **Normalized Mutual Information**: measures the agreement of the two assignments.
- **Silhouette Coefficient**: measures how well-assigned each individual point is.

```
gmm.fit(x_vec)

pred = gmm.predict(x_vec)

print ("gmm: silhouttte: ", silhouette_score(x_vec, pred))
```

Comment: could you provide an example or how to apply it to my case and how to interpreter the results. the documentation of sklearn not always helpful for me. thanks

Comment: i think these metrics for classification task. What i am doing is a density estimation using Gaussian Mixture. But thanks anyway!

Comment: You can use the Silhouette metric for unsupervised task. It calculates how similar an object is to its own cluster compared to other cluster. @MWH

Comment: thanks. i am geing error "ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:". does this supposed to work with data with one column (X) only?? i passed x "original data" and y "sampled data", both have same data points "rows".

Comment: @MWH I added a small example to my answer how you can use silhouette score metrics for your cluster.

Comment: thanks it works now returning a value between -1 and 1. But from what i understand this score is to deteremine number of clusters, e.g., components in GMM. I already decided that using AIC/BIC creteria. Still do not get will this score is a goodness of fit one to show how well is the fitted GMM distribution? or just to parameterize the model?

Comment: To determine the number of clusters you can use elbow method. After clustering operation you can check silhouette score and try to understand your cluster structure.

Comment: @MWH If the solution works for you, could you please vote it?

Comment: i did, but still not sure if this the right answer to my case. I am using GMM as density estimation (not as clustering) to fit a distribution to data, following this tutorial https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jakevdp/ESAC-stats-2014/blob/master/notebooks/05.3-Density-GMM.ipynb. If you explain why this solution would work for me as an evaluation metric or add more details, i might accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would better use cross-validation and try to see the accuracy of the trained model.

Use the `predict` method of the fitted model to predict the labels of unseen data (use cross-validation and report the acurracy): https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html#sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.predict

Toy example:

```
g = GaussianMixture(n_components = 35)
g.fit(train_data)# fit model
y_pred = g.predict(test_data)
```

EDIT:

There are several options to measure the performance of your **unsupervised** case. For GMM, which base on real probabilities, the most common are BIC and AIC. They are immediatly included in the scikit GMM class.

Comment: to best of my knowledge, cross validation works only if we have 2D, e.g., X and y, we pass X, predict y and compare it with original y (tehn calculate mean absolut error etc). In my case, i only have X, so when i sample i got completely different numbers, possibily. Correct me if i am wrong!

Comment: I see your point. In case you use GMM as an unsupervised model, then my answer cannot be used. In other words, if you do not have labels (`y`), you cannot use this proposed cross-validation scheme. see my edit

Comment: Thanks. I already used AIC/BIC to guide me on # of componentes. But i am looking for evaluating the accuracy, i only found score which i do not understand well.